# Why does a mySQL Python Query not insert a new entry?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

So I am trying to add a new entry into my mySQL Database.
The problem here is, that it increases the id, but does add the entry.
After a little bit of googling I found that a failed `INSERT` query also increases the `AUTO_INCREMENT`d value (`id` in my case).

The mySQL Table is created using
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TS3_STAMM_1 (id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, ts3_uid VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, points INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL);` which is called by the function `qServer.execute(querystring)` inside python's `MySQLdb` module.

Then I use `qString = "INSERT INTO TS3_STAMM_1 (name, ts3_uid, points) VALUES ('{}', '{}', {})".format(name, uid, pnts)` (the datatypes are correct, I at least quadrouplechecked) with the function `qServer.exectue(qString)` to insert a new entry into the database.

But it is incrementing the ID, but its not adding an entry. So my guess would be its a failed query, but why? How does it happen? How to fix it?

Simple `SELECT` querys work fine the same way, also adding data manually works fine. Only the python query fails.

Note: `qServer` is the connection to the server, and its defined with:

```
try:
    qConn = MySQLdb.connect(host="...", user="...", passwd="...", db="...")
    qServer = qConn.cursor()
except OperationalError:
    print("Cannot connect to mySQL Database! Aborting...")
    exit(1)
```

Comment: Please do not use string formatting for passing arguments. That's a footgun for many reason, SQL injection being the worst. Use your DB-API driver's placeholders and pass args to `execute()` separately. In your incomplete example you never show a call to commit. If you do not commit, no data is persisted.

Comment: The lack of the `commit()` seems to have been the cause of the data not saving... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use commit Luke.

```
>>> cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employees (first_name) VALUES (%s)", ('Jane', ))
>>> qConn.commit()
```

Using `str.format` for creating SQL query is bad idea.

Comment: What is cnx in this case?

Comment: It is connection object qConn in your case.

Comment: How would that formatting approach look for more variables? I tried it with `%s, %s, %d` and on the `%d` it says `%d format: a number is required, not str`. This happens even when I make sure and put the `pnts` variable in the `int()` function. My approach right now is to use `[...].execute("[...]", (name, uid, int(pnts)))` but this cannot format on the  `%d` since it thinks that pnts is a string, even when I mark it as int

Comment: Nevermind, I found it out. You can only format with one formatting placeholder, either `%d` or `%s`. But `%s` is fine, I can just convert it to a string. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to convert to string, and `int()` does not mark anything, but creates a new integer. The driver creates suitable SQL for each value based on its type and in case of MySQLdb driver the [placeholder is always %s](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples), and is **not Python's old style %-formatting**.